# How handle ldap request when getting 'Server is busy'

Tags: python, ldap

I have found python way to get data from ldap, there is a part where i have problem with

```
    try:
        ldap_result_id = ldapcon.search(base, scope, search_filter, attributes)
        result_set = []
        while 1:
            result_type, result_data = ldapcon.result(ldap_result_id, 0)
            if (result_data == []):
                break
            else:
                if result_type == ldap.RES_SEARCH_ENTRY:
                    result_set.append(result_data)
    except ldap.LDAPError, e:
        print e
```

but mostly i have got ldap error on "ldapcon.result()"

```
{'info': '00002024: LdapErr: DSID-0C060598, comment: No other operations may be performed on the connection while a bind is outstanding., data 0, v1db1', 'desc': 'Server is busy'}
```

it happens 2 times from 3, so on next try it can succeed!
do you have some nice idea how to handle it?
put the same try/except only for that function and add some attempt counter?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i can't say if it's elegant and right, but it works

```
 while 1:
     try:
        ldap_result_id = ldapcon.search(base, scope, search_filter, attributes)
        result_set = []
        result_type, result_data = ldapcon.result(ldap_result_id, 0, 2)
    except ldap.LDAPError, e:
        pass
    if 'result_data' in locals():
        if result_type == ldap.RES_SEARCH_ENTRY:
            result_set.append(result_data)
        return result_set[0][0][1]['departmentNumber'][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am learning about this right now.  I hope this helps.  I found the following that seems to do exactly what I need:

`ldap.ldapobject.ReconnectLDAPObject(dc, retry_max=5, retry_delay=2.0)`

For more info, check out https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldap.html#ldap-objects